# How to use unsupported language?

Tags: python, django, localization

I can switch to `ru` and `en`, but when i try to switch to `hy`, nothing happens.

*settings.py*

```
...
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en',_('English')),
    ('ru', _(u'Russian')),
    ('hy', _(u'Armenian')),
]
```

*sidebar.html*

```
...
<div id="sidebar-item-news">
        <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" id="language-select">
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
            {% csrf_token %}
            <select name="language">
                {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                    <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form>
</div>
```

*urls.py*

```
# Internationalization
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

After some debugging i figured out that request.session['django_language'] changes only to `ru` and `en`:

```
Current language is ru
[19/May/2012 22:51:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13357
[19/May/2012 22:51:56] "POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Current language is ru
[19/May/2012 22:51:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13357
```

I have all compiled translation files in `/locale/hy` and `/locale/ru`

If i put in home view `translation.activate('hy')` it works perfectly, but if i try to do this with my api

```
def api(request, type):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if type == 'daytime':
            request.session['daytime'] = request.POST['daytime']
            return HttpResponse(request.session['daytime'])

        if type == 'language':
            request.session['custom_language'] = True
            request.session['django_language'] = request.POST['language']
            translation.activate(request.session['django_language'] )
            return HttpResponse(request.session['django_language'])
        raise Http404
    else:
        raise Http404
```

It fails as the `i18n/setlang` form.

How to fix this?

**UPD**
It seems that Django does **not** support armenian. (there is no 'hy' in /django/conf/locale/)
How should i work with this language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Locale restriction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files) section in i18n docs. Looks like you need to modify Django a little.

Comment: I just need to translate django core strings in my project? Or i need to add new language to django/conf/local?

Comment: As I can see - you should add new language to django itself.